# Export XML data to Excel using C#

Tags: c#, xml, excel, linq

```
XML:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> 
<IMPORT ExportDate="2016-03-02" Exercise="1" User="asa" Version="8.73" BusinessUnit="abc(1236)">

   <BusinessUnitAdmin>
    ...
    ...
    </BusinessUnitAdmin>
   <BusinessUnit>
    ..
    ..
    </BusinessUnit>
    <Exercise>
    ..
    ..
     </Exercise>
     <Exercise>
     ..
     ..
     </Exercise>
     <Contact>
     ..
     </Contact>
 </IMPORT>
```

I am trying to export this XML to Excel, while also maintaining the schema of XML.
For this, I have tried converting the XML to Dataset and then exporting it to Excel.
It works correctly if I remove the root element - IMPORT from the XML. However since it has '**BusinessUnit** as attribute, its preventing to read "BusinessUnit" as element.
For this, I am trying to read XML from second element `- <BusinessUnitAdmin>` ; but unable to do.

C# Code:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
string path = "C:\\abc\\xyz.xml";
ds.ReadXml(path);                         //throws error
ExportDataSetToExcel(ds);
```

Error: "A column named 'BusinessUnit' already belongs to this DataTable: cannot set a nested table name to the same name."

I have tried using LINQ:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path);
XElement import = xdoc.Element("IMPORT");
XElement contact = import.Element("Contact");
StringReader theReader = new StringReader(contact.ToString());
ds.ReadXml(theReader);
```

It works correctly, but this way, I have to manually read all elements.

I also tried reading elements using - `var allElements = xdoc.Descendants()`;
 but unable to store specific elements in dataset.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem *isn't* that you can't export your XML data into Excel.

The problem is actually that you can't convert your XML - which is in a tree-based hierarchical format - into a 2D array of values, ready to be exported to Excel.

I mean, if your XML contained three levels of hierarchy, how would you expect Excel to display this ?!

Anyway, let me answer the *second* part of your question.

If you can get your data in a regular 2-dimensional format, either as a `DataSet` or `DataTable`, then you can use my free C# class to write it to an .xlsx file using one line of code.

[Export to Excel](http://www.mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/CSharp/ExportToExcel.htm)

Now, you just need to get your data into a usable format.

Over to you...!